# AWS IAM Users vs Secure Token Services (Keys On Demand)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-iam

I'm trying to better understand the potential of AWS Secure Token Service, and looking for thoughts on how best to solve a particular problem.

Let's say I have a bunch of IAM users that are currently fairly well carved up into different groups that restrict access to the AWS services that are needed (admins, dba's, datawarehouse, etc.). However, even with this setup, there are still a bunch of long-lived keys that will inevitably end up hard coded into various utils, committed to version control for all to see, etc. You can manually rotate all of these keys, of course, but that's a lot of effort.

So, it seemed to me that a better solution was to adopt a stance of "keys on demand". The IAM user accounts remain intact, and associated with the groups that grant them whatever access comes with that group, but without active API keys, the accounts are useless. I started writing a python app that first authenticates users against LDAP internally, and then allows them to click a button to generate a new API key for their AWS account. Then, I would run a cron job every minute or hour or whatever, to find keys that are older than 12 hours, send an API call to AWS to delete that key.

I got about 80% done with that, and stumbled on STS. Is my scenario a perfect use-case for STS? Could I just create roles that mirror the various permission sets I need, and allow IAM users to have default stance of no access, but assume a role on demand?

Anything else I need to be considering? I.e. anything that might break by implementing something along these lines?

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  I've been working on something like this, too.  The STS service, specifically the AssumeRole operation, is perfect for this because it creates temporary credentials that automatically expire so you don't have to manage that yourself.  Setting up the cross-account roles is tricky and its a PITA that Roles cannot be members of Groups in IAM so if you already have Groups that have the right policies you have to duplicate those in Roles.  I didn't write this as an answer because I'm not really providing an answer other than to say you are on the right track 8^)

Comment: OK thanks :) At least I'm not the only one heading down this path.

Comment: If I get my stuff to the point where its working and is not completely specific to my purpose, I'll put it up on github.